# python formatting issue parsing child element

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I am parsing an xml file that lists some servers

example xml for 2 server:

```
<cluster-information>
    <clustering-available>true</clustering-available>
    <clustered>true</clustered>
    <node>
      <id>SomeIDnum</id>
      <address>/someIP:port</address>
      <local>false</local>
    </node>
    <node>
      <id>SomeIDnum</id>
      <address>/someIP:port</address>
      <local>false</local>
    </node>
  </cluster-information>
```

I am using the following to get the ID and Address

```
cluster=myroot.find('cluster-information/clustered')
if cluster.text == 'true':
    print("|Cluster is "+cluster.text+" |")
    nodes=myroot.find('cluster-information')
    for x in nodes.findall('node'):
        id=x.find('id')
        ip=x.find('address')
        print("Node:"+id.text)
        print("IP "+ip.text)
    print("|")
```

The result is:

|Cluster is true |
Node:someID
IP /x.x.x.x:port
Node:someotherID
IP /x.x.x.x:port
|

I need to the output to look like this:
|Cluster is true |Node:someID
IP /x.x.x.x:port
Node:someotherID
IP /x.x.x.x:port
|

Basically I need to remove the first newline that is created form the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to remove the first newline that is created form the for loop.

That *first newline* isn't *created form the for loop* - it is generated by the

```
    print("|Cluster is "+cluster.text+" |")
```

before the loop. To remove it, change to

```
    print("|Cluster is "+cluster.text+" |", end="")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was easy = )